# How can I cache a list of entries with pending postDates and have it automatically invalidate the cache appropriately?

Tags: postdate, pending

I have a listing page of entries, some of which may have future-dated postDates. I want to cache the output, but only until one of the pending entries goes live.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Easy! Get the most soonest upcoming pending entry, and use `until`:

```
{% set firstPending = craft.entries({
  section: 'articles',
  status: 'pending',
  order: 'postDate asc'
}).first %}
{% set cacheUntil = firstPending ? firstPending.postDate : now|date_modify('+1 year') %}

{% set content %}
    {% cache until cacheUntil %}
        ...
    {% endcache %}
{% endset %}
```

Note that this solution requires [Craft 2.2.2598](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2598) or later.

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to include the `until` statement conditionally all-together, that way you wouldn't need to do `now|date_modify('+1 year')`

Comment: `if craft.config.enableCache` is just a custom config var I'm using, doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: Just FYI... It's not necessary to specify "limit: 1" when you're using `.first`.

Comment: Changed my code to reflect that!

Comment: Your original solution will work with a small tweak to the way cache clearing works in Craft. The next update will include that tweak.

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to it. Thanks, B!

Comment: @TimKelty As of [Craft 2.2.2598](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2598) your original solution should work. Give it a shot!